# Three20 and Unsigned Certificates

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl, webview, three20

I am re-writing my app using the Three20 library. In my app, I am opening links to various websites, some which contain websites that have unsigned certs.

In my non-three20 app, this is how I am loading such websites (using ASIHTTPRequest):

```
//=======================================================================================
// Once the correct URL is set, load it using ASIHTTPRequest
-(void)loadURL:(NSURL *)localURL
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    if(regularLoad)
    {
    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:localURL];
    [webView loadRequest:req];
    regularLoad = false;
} else {
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:localURL];
    [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous]; 
    [request release];
    }
}

//=======================================================================================
// Delegate method for ASIHTTPRequest 
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [webView loadHTMLString:responseString baseURL:request.url];
}
```

The main part of that is webView's loadHTMLString method, which a Three20 TTWebController does not have.

Has anyone been able to accomplish this in Three20? I have scoured the net and on here, but have found no solutions.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the TTWebController class and add the missing loadHTMLString function yourself.

```
@interface WebController : TTWebController

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@implementation WebController

- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL {
  [_webView loadHTMLString:string baseURL:baseURL;];
}
```

You will need to create the web controller using the init function and not call it using the TTNavigator, so you will have a reference to it

Comment: might make senses to add it to the three20 as a improvement. the issue is that it would be an issue calling that function using the TTNavigator..